# group users and find top 3 mentioned users inR

Tags: r, group-by, tweets, mention

I have aa data frame `df` with only one column `mentions`.

```
  mentions
 _________
 1   @one
 2   @two
 3   @one
 4   @four
      ...
```

I want to find the most mentioned user.
I tried
`group_by(df)` but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Thank you! Question solved with  `df %>% group_by(mentions) %>% summarise(n = n())
newdf <- df[order(df$n, decreasing = TRUE),]
head(newdf, 1)`

Answer (score 2):

```
rev(sort(table(df$mentions)))[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

The confusion here arises from the fact that group by tells R how to apply the next few calculations. This means that we want to actually count using the group of mentions.

I would suggest using the `%>%` function followed by `count()`.

I have provided a reproducible example below:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(~L,
        "a",
        "a",
        "a",
        "a",
        "a",
        "b",
        "b",
        "b",
        "b", 
        "c",
        "c",
        "c",
        "c",
        "c")

df %>% 
  group_by(L) %>% 
  count() %>% 
  arrange(desc(n))
```

Try this but replace df and L with your df and mentions as that would be your data.